# trying to figure out how to get the next values using a loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for some resource, my code print the first unequal value between two txt files. what I am trying to do is how to get to the next unequal values if I press a key. I think the while loop would help, but I fail in every logic. any resource where I could find some answers?

```
def textdiff():
    text1 = open("text1.txt", "r")
    text2 = open("text2.txt", "r")
    for orgtext1 in text2:
        for oldtext2 in text1:
            if oldtext2 != orgtext1:
                return oldtext2
        text1.close()
        text2.close()


print(textdiff())
```

thanks a lot

Comment: do you want to compare the nth character of text file 1 with text file 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to compare the nth character of file 1 with the nth character of file 2, I would use [`yield`](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) to jump out of the function after each found inequality and the [`with`](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python) statement to make sure that the files are properly closed if an error is raised:

```
def textdiff():
    with open("text1.txt", "r") as file1:
        with open("text2.txt", "r") as file2:
            text1 = file1.read()
            text2 = file2.read()
            shared_length = min(len(text1), len(text2))
            for pos in range(shared_length):
                if text1[pos] != text2[pos]:
                    yield text1[pos] + " != " + text2[pos]

for diff in textdiff():
    print(diff)
    input('Press <Return> to continue')
```

Comment: Thank you @mrzo. This looks perfect